# How to create a pointer between two classes?

Tags: c++

I want to make a train class and car class. I want to have three cars inside the train. The cars are pointed to each other so i can easily go from one to another.

```
class Train{   
 // link other car, so i can go from one to another 
 // pointer to the engine 

};
class car{   
 // cargo weight and pointer to next car and way to know we are in caboose
};
```

This is what I did:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Train.h"
int main()
{
    Train* engine;
    car* cars = new car();
    return 0;
}
```

**Header file:**

```
#ifndef TRAIN_H
#define TRAIN_H
class Train
{
  public:
    Train()
    {
        int* space = new int [3];
    }

    ~Train();
};

class car
{
   public:
      int cargo_weight;
      int wieght;
      car()
      {
        int* number = new int [3];
      }
      ~car();
       car* Next;       
       private:     
         car* head;
         car* tail;
 };
#endif
```

Comment: it's unclear what's your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an aside:

```
Train(): firstCar(nullptr)
{
    int* space = new int [3];
}
```

`space` is a pointer to an int. Doesn't do much good if you want to hold `Car`s, but what's nasty is `space` only exists within the curly braces of `Train`'s constructor. The three integers it points to are lost. Not deleted or freed, but lost, and without a pointer to tell you where to find those 3 `int`s it's damn hard to release their memory. This is called a memory leak and is generally considered a bad scene.

Next, `Car` has both `head`, `tail`, and `next`. This makes `Car` both a linked list element and a linked list. Rather odd and probably not necessary. Let the `Train` act as the linked list. It has reason to know the chain of `Car`s while each car has no reason to know anything other than the next, and possibly previous, `Car`.

And onward...

It appears that you want to chain up to three `Car`s together in a `Train`. First thing the `Train` needs is a pointer to the first `Car`in the chain.

```
class Train
{
  private:
    Car * firstCar;
  public:
    Train(): firstCar(nullptr) // ensure that the first car point at a sentinel value
                               // otherwise we're in for a while world of hurt later
    {
    }

    ~Train();
};
```

And you'll need a method to add a car.

```
bool linkCar(Car * newcar)
{
    if (firstCar != nullptr) // if there is no first car. 
                             // See told you we'd need a sentinel!
    { 
        firstCar = newcar; // this car is the first car
    }
    else
    {
        firstCar->linkCar(newcar); //tell the first car to link to the new car
    }
}
```

This means that `Car` needs a `linkCar` method

```
bool linkCar(Car * newcar)
{
    if (next != nullptr) // if this car is the last car in the train add the new car here 
    {
        next = newcar;
    }
    else
    { // not the last car. Keep looking until we find the last car
        next->linkCar(newcar);
    }
}
```

And to make that work, `Car::next` must be initialised in the constructor to `nullptr`.

```
car():next(nullptr)
{
}
```

Unfortunately this approach is kind of poor unless the instructor demands you build a singly linked list of cars. For one thing, you need a bunch of extra book-keeping to stop you from adding a fourth car. You may need a bunch of extra logic to release all of the cars you've allocated. You have to make sure that the car-releasing logic is called. And if the instructor wants a doubly linked list, at best what I have above provides a starting point. Fortunately there are dozens, if not thousands, of examples of how to build a doubly linked list on Stack Overflow.

Instead, store a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of `Car`s

```
class Train
{
  private:
    std::vector<Car> cars;
  public:
    Train()
    {
    }
    bool addCar(Car &newcar)
    {
        if (cars.size() < 3)
        {
            cars.push_back(newcar);
        }
    }
};
```

Note we don't need a destructor anymore because we have nothing that needs destroying. `std::vector` handles all of it for us.

Car doesn't need to know about anything but themselves. No link to the next car is required. No destructor is needed because all of `car`s resources are self-managed.

```
class car
{
   private:
      int cargo_weight;
      int weight;
   public:
      car()
      {
      }
 };
```

The `car` constructor should probably be expanded to set the weights so that each car is ready to go right out of the box.

```
car(int c_weight, int car_weight): 
    cargo_weight(c_weight),
    weight(car_weight)
{
}
```